# Combine the Data of two SQL databases to one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL databases with the same schema. Both have different Data but are using the same primary keys. I want to add the Data from one database to the second one, but all solution I found just update the rows with the same primary keys and dont attach them at the end.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: How about `UNION ALL` ?

Comment: Which dbms? (Product specific question.)

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3

Comment: ok, what do you want to do if you don't want to merge... you want to assign new keys to the new records?

Comment: yes, if in a row is different data but with the same primary key I want new keys for one of the rows. so both rows will be in the database

Comment: Take a look at the SCD2 merge example www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2012/01/using-t-sql-merge-to-load-data-warehouse-dimensions/

Answer (score 0):

If your primary key column is an ID field that uses an auto-incrementing sequence (if not, then how would you choose a different primary key for overlapping records anyway?), you should just be able to insert the records from the first schema, excluding the ID in your select query.

For example:

**Table Schema:**

```
ID     INT(10) 
Name   VARCHAR(20)
Desc   TEXT
```

**SQL**

```
INSERT INTO schema2.table (Name, Desc)
SELECT Name, Desc
  FROM schema1.table
```